# F4 IDE gives "Invalid Uri scheme for local file" when running Fantom app

Tags: ide, fantom

I started a very simple project using Xored's F4 IDE for Fantom. The first few times I ran it there was no error, but I started adding dependencies (fanbatis) and at some point the error below starting showing up every time I run a test or a dummy Hello World app.

```
[23:44:18 22-Nov-13] [err] [pathenv] Cannot parse path: C:\dev\f4workspace\auth\bin\fan
  sys::ArgErr: Invalid Uri scheme for local file: c:\dev\f4workspace\auth\bin\fan/
    fan.sys.LocalFile.uriToFile (LocalFile.java:64)
    fan.sys.File.make (File.java:26)
    util::PathEnv.parsePath (PathEnv.fan:47)
    fan.sys.List.each (List.java:555)
    util::PathEnv.parsePath (PathEnv.fan:43)
    util::PathEnv.make$ (PathEnv.fan:22)
    util::PathEnv.make (PathEnv.fan:20)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown)
    fan.sys.Method.invoke (Method.java:559)
    fan.sys.Method$MethodFunc.callList (Method.java:198)
    fan.sys.Type.make (Type.java:246)
    fan.sys.ClassType.make (ClassType.java:110)
    fan.sys.Type.make (Type.java:236)
    fan.sys.Sys.initEnv (Sys.java:447)
    fan.sys.Sys. (Sys.java:224)
    fanx.tools.Fan.execute (Fan.java:28)
    fanx.tools.Fan.run (Fan.java:298)
    fanx.tools.Fan.main (Fan.java:336)
Hello, World!
```

It is more a nuisance at the moment because the tests and the dummy app still run. I created another project, copying all the source code adding class by class and testing after each change and the error never occurred. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting issue!

**tl/dr**: you have an empty project 'auth' in your workspace, either create some dummy class inside it or go to Run -> Run configurations, find your launch config and uncheck project without sources on 'Projects' tab.

In order to keep your Fantom installation clean from projects in a workspace, F4 puts built pods into project/bin/fan/lib/fan. When F4 launches projects from workspace, it uses [PathEnv](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Env.html#PathEnv) and builds FAN_ENV_PATH by joining paths to Fantom installation and bin/ folders in projects in workspace.

When Fantom runtime analyzes FAN_ENV_PATH, at first it interprets a path as native OS path, but if dir does not exist, it attempts to interpret it as file URI, here's relevant part of PathEnv source:

```
path.split(File.pathSep[0]).each |item|
{
  if (item.isEmpty) return
  dir := File.os(item).normalize
  if (!dir.exists) dir = File(item.toUri.plusSlash, false).normalize
  if (!dir.exists) { log.warn("Dir not found: $dir"); return }
```

The problem code is item.toUri – On Mac OS X and Linux this is parsed as an URI without scheme with path only, so if directory does not exist, this code just prints a warning in a console.

But on Windows, because of disk name in path, disk name is interpreted as scheme:

```
fansh> "C:\\Users".toUri { echo(path); echo(scheme) }
[\Users]
c
fansh> "/Users".toUri { echo(path); echo(scheme) }
[Users]
null
```

And then File constructor fails, because expects either 'file' scheme, or null scheme:

```
public static java.io.File uriToFile(Uri uri)
{
  if (uri.scheme() != null && !uri.scheme().equals("file"))
    throw ArgErr.make("Invalid Uri scheme for local file: " + uri);
  return new java.io.File(uriToPath(uri));
}
```

I've created an issue here, so that F4 would automatically skip empty projects when building FAN_ENV_PATH – https://github.com/xored/f4/issues/25.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem had something to do with the forward slash at the end of path as shown in this line of the error message

```
Invalid Uri scheme for local file: c:\dev\f4workspace\auth\bin\fan/
```

However, I found that such path didn't exist. I manually created both the bin and the fan folders and the error disappeared. To be honest I don't really know why F4 needs and checks for that folder because so far it hasn't written any file in it.

Comment: In my experience F4 usually creates the directories it needs, so I've never seen this particular error. 

How did you add the src folder `fan/` to the project?

I `right click on the project --> New --> Fantom Source Folder`, if you manually added it to `build.fan` then that could be a possible cause.